# Calculating the contour integral of a non-meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to compute the following contour integral, which superficially looks like Cauchy's integral formula,

$$ \int_{|z|=R} \frac{\log(|z-w|)}{z-w} dz $$

where $w \in D(0,R)$ is fixed.

Is there a way to get a closed form for this in terms of $R$ and $w$? I've been trying to find a way to use complex analysis but nothing seems to stick.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll try to use Dilogarithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=Re^{i\theta}, w=re^{ia}, \frac{r}{R}=c < 1, dz=izd\theta, \frac{1}{z-w}=\frac{1}{z}(\sum_{k \ge 0}\frac{w^k}{z^k})=\frac{1}{z}(\sum_{k \ge 0}c^ke^{ik(a-\theta)})$,

so the integral becomes:

$I=i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\log(|z-w|)(\sum_{k \ge 0}c^ke^{ik(a-\theta)})d\theta$

But now $|z-w|=|z||1-\frac{w}{z}|$, so $\log(|z-w|=\log R + \log|1-\frac{w}{z}|=\log R + \Re{\log(1-\frac{w}{z})}=$

$=\log R - \Re{(\sum_{m \ge 1}\frac{w^m}{mz^m}})=\log R-\sum_{m \ge 1}\frac{c^m\cos{m(a-\theta})}{m}$

Putting this together we get:

$I=2\pi i \log R-i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{k\ge 0, m\ge 1}\frac{c^{m+k}e^{ik{(a-\theta)}}\cos{m(a-\theta})}{m}d\theta$,

By periodicity all terms cancel except $k=m \ge 1$ where the $\theta$ integral is just $\pi$, so we get:

$I=2\pi i \log R-\pi i\sum_{m \ge 1}\frac{c^{2m}}{m} =2\pi i \log R+\pi i\log{(1-c^2)}=\pi i\log{(R^2-r^2)}$

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem and happy to help